# $I_n= \int_{-1}^1 (1 − x^2 )^n \cos(ax) \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

I was given this problem in my Analysis class and I'm very stuck.

> Fix a non-zero number $a$. For $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ define
>   $$I_n= \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n(\cos(ax)) \mathrm dx$$
>   Use integration by parts to show that
>   $$I_n = 2n(2n−1)a^{−2}(I_{n−1})−4n(n−1)a^{-2}(I_{n-2})$$
>   where $n = 2, 3, 4, \ldots$

I first tried integrating by parts where 
$u=(1-x^2)^n$ and $v=\sin(ax)/a $, but the resulting formula needs to be integrated by parts again and I'm not sure what to choose for my $u$ and $v$ to be.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate by parts twice, separating the trig function from the polynomial each time. Then remember that $x^2=1-\left(1-x^2\right)$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1(1−x^2)^n\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac1a\int_{-1}^1(1−x^2)^n\,\mathrm{d}\sin(ax)\\
&=\frac{2n}a\int_{-1}^1x\,(1−x^2)^{n-1}\sin(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{2n}{a^2}\int_{-1}^1x\,(1−x^2)^{n-1}\,\mathrm{d}\cos(ax)\\
&=\frac{2n}{a^2}\int_{-1}^1\left[(1−x^2)^{n-1}-2(n-1)x^2(1−x^2)^{n-2}\right]\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{2n}{a^2}\int_{-1}^1\left[(2n-1)(1−x^2)^{n-1}-2(n-1)(1−x^2)^{n-2}\right]\cos(ax)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{2n}{a^2}\left[(2n-1)I_{n-1}-(2n-2)I_{n-2}\right]
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We use the fact that all $n$ are positive integers to write:

$$I_n=\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n \cos(ax) \mathrm dx= $$$$=\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^{n-1} \cos(ax) \mathrm dx-\int_{-1}^1 x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1} \cos(ax) \mathrm dx$$

The latter integral has a different form, but we can try using integration by parts there with:

$$u= x \cos (ax)$$

$$dv=-x (1-x^2)^{n-1} dx$$

$$du= (\cos (ax) - a x \sin (ax))dx$$

$$v=\frac{1}{2n} (1-x^2)^n$$

We obtain:

$$-\int_{-1}^1 x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1} \cos(ax) \mathrm dx=-\frac{1}{2n} \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n (\cos (ax) - a x \sin (ax))dx$$

So we have:

$$\left(1+ \frac{1}{2n}\right) I_n=I_{n-1} + \frac{a}{2n} \int_{-1}^1 x(1-x^2)^n \sin (ax) dx$$

We use integration by parts again with:

$$dv=x(1-x^2)^n$$

$$u=\sin (ax)$$

$$v= - \frac{1}{2(n+1)} (1-x^2)^{n+1}$$

$$du=a \cos (ax)$$

So we have:

$$\int_{-1}^1 x(1-x^2)^n \sin (ax) dx= \frac{a}{2(n+1)} \int_{-1}^1  (1-x^2)^{n+1} \cos (ax) dx$$

And we obtain:

$$\left(1+ \frac{1}{2n}\right) I_n=I_{n-1} + \frac{a^2}{4n(n+1)} I_{n+1}$$

Or, rewriting:

$$a^2 I_{n+1}=2(n+1)(2n+1) I_n-4n(n+1) I_{n-1}$$

Shifting the index by $1$:

> $$a^2 I_n=2n(2n-1) I_{n-1}-4n(n-1) I_{n-2}$$

Comment: You have trouble with I0?

Comment: @McGreer, write down I0 explicitly please. It's just cos. As for I1, you will need to use integration by parts with u=x^2 and then again with u=x

Comment: I got it, thank you for your help. Now on to proving pi is irrational with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you need to get from $I_n$ to $I_{n-1}$ and $I_{n-2}$, and $n$ shows up in the integrand as the exponent to a polynomial, it follows that you're going to have to differentiate the polynomial and integrate the trig function. ILATE would have you do that anyway. You're going to keep doing the same thing: let $u$ be the poly, and $dv$ be the trig plus the $dx$.